# The C compiler is not able to compile a simple test program CLion and mingw-w64

Tags: c++, compilation, clion, mingw-w64

I'm now at C++. Some tome ago I wrote program in CLion with mingw-w64. After some vacation I thied to use CLion again but have next error:

> 

The C compiler

```
"C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.3.4/bin/mingw/bin/gcc.exe"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: C:/Users/ADMIN/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug-mingw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.3.4/bin/ninja/win/ninja.exe cmTC_8c5e5 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c5e5.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_8c5e5.exe
FAILED: cmTC_8c5e5.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.4\bin\mingw\bin\gcc.exe   CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c5e5.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -o cmTC_8c5e5.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_8c5e5.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

> 

What is the reason of error and how I can fix it.
Thanks a lot! I wish you good code)

Comment: The file in the command line is `CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c5e5.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj` but that is not a full path - so it could be looking anywhere.  The way it looks to me is that it is trying to find `C:/Users/ADMIN/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug-mingw/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c5e5.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj` but that probably isn't where the file is.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, thank you for your help, but how can I try to fix it?)